# Laravel - JWT Auth The token could not be parsed from the request

Tags: php, laravel-5, jwt

I have added following code in my middleware for user authentication with [JWT Auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth), which works fine for all the routes handled by the middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->has('token')) {
        try {
            $this->auth = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
            return $next($request);
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return redirect()->guest('user/login');
        }
    }
}
```

But for one route with **Post Method** where the token is getting passed properly but still I am getting :

> JWTException - The token could not be parsed from the request

on the same route when I tried :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->has('token')) {
        try {
            dd($request->input('token'));
            $this->auth = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
            return $next($request);
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return redirect()->guest('user/login');
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9iaXNzIjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwMDFcL2F1dGhcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNDcyNTI4NDU0LCJleHAiOjE0NzI1MzIwNTQsIm5iZiI6MTQ3MjUyODQ1NCwianRpIjoiM2E0M2ExYTZlNmM5NjUxZDgxYjZhNDcxMzkxODJlYjAifQ.CH8ES2ADTCrVWeIO8uU31bGDnH7h-ZVTWxrdXraLw8s"
```

I am able to see the Valid Token which I am using to access another routes and which is working flawlessly for all other routes.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your description, I checked source file of JWT Auth.

In class `Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth` line 191 - 219 , there are two functions:

```
/**
 * Parse the token from the request.
 *
 * @param string $query
 *
 * @return JWTAuth
 */
public function parseToken($method = 'bearer', $header = 'authorization', $query = 'token')
{
    if (! $token = $this->parseAuthHeader($header, $method)) {
        if (! $token = $this->request->query($query, false)) {
            throw new JWTException('The token could not be parsed from the request', 400);
        }
    }

    return $this->setToken($token);
}

/**
 * Parse token from the authorization header.
 *
 * @param string $header
 * @param string $method
 *
 * @return false|string
 */
protected function parseAuthHeader($header = 'authorization', $method = 'bearer')
{
    $header = $this->request->headers->get($header);

    if (! starts_with(strtolower($header), $method)) {
        return false;
    }

    return trim(str_ireplace($method, '', $header));
}
```

Check the logic of them, I believe your request header is not properly provided.

```
if (! $token = $this->parseAuthHeader($header, $method)) { // all your get method not passed this step
   if (! $token = $this->request->query($query, false)) { // all your post method stucked here 
       throw new JWTException('The token could not be parsed from the request', 400);
   }
}
```

A properly formatted header looks like this :

```
http POST http://${host}/api/v1/product/favorite/111 "Authorization: Bearer ${token}"
```

That's all I can offer to you, hope it will help you through your thoughts. If it won't you can still debug those two functions.

Comment: @akshaykhale,hope this helped you.if so, please take my answer. so we both can get reputations

Comment: Yup, your answer was very helpful, the JWTAuth file was unable to read token from the request. thanks for help.

Comment: Posting the code doing the reading was what I needed to fix my requests. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on ec2 amazon AMI Linux php7.2 apache2.4 but token get generated in apache request headers but was not visible in Laravel request header
so add this code in middleware this will work only on your server but may not work on localhost.

```
 $headers = apache_request_headers();
 $request->headers->set('Authorization', $headers['authorization']);
```

JWT middleware

```
    try {
            $headers = apache_request_headers(); //get header
            $request->headers->set('Authorization', $headers['authorization']);// set header in request

            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException){
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Invalid']);
            }else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException){
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Expired']);
            }else{
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Authorization Token not found']);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help. This solution worked for me, just to make it more accurate : in my case i was getting authentication token in this  `$headers['Authorization']` array.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it by adding `RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]` to the `.htaccess`, so the authorization header does not get discarded by Laravel. Might be useful to add this to the docs.

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple
  questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions).
  Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn
  enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the
  question and flag for undeletion.

Answer (score 2):

> I faced an issue and got solution from adding below lines in
> .htaccess

---

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I add this in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

(remember to restart your apache)

Removing `index.php` from my url, resolve this problem.

`/public/index.php/api/user/login` -> `/public/api/user/login`